# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{3}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

About 2 weeks ago, I tried to solve the following problem.

> Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{3}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My attempt**

First, I tried to find the polynomial with rational(integer) coefficients having $\alpha$ as a root, and $f(x)=x^6-6x^4+12x^2-11$ is a polynomial such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Unfortunately, $6$ and $12$ is not divided by $11$, so I could not use the Eisenstein's criterion.

Instead of directly showing that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, I tried to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=6$. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2):\mathbb{Q}]$ and $\alpha^2=2+\sqrt[3]{3}$, we know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. Thus if we succeed to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2)]=2$, then the proof is over. However, I could not do it.

I supposed that $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$, then there are $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\alpha=a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}.
$$
By squaring both sides of the equation, we obtain
$$
(a^2-6bc-2)+(3c^2-2ab-1)\sqrt[3]{3}+(b^2+2ca)\sqrt[3]{9}=0
$$
and $a^2-6bc-2=3c^2-2ab-1=b^2+2ca=0$. However, I don't know how to show that this system of equations does not have a rational root and I'm stuck here.

**Question:** Is there a (or an alternative) way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an alternative solution, but I think I can continue from where you have left.

So you were trying to show that there is no rational solution to
$$
2 + \sqrt[3]{3} = (a + b \sqrt[3]{3} + c\sqrt[3]{9})^2
$$

Taking the field norm (in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) of both sides, you get $11 = r^2$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ which is absurd.

Comment: I learned the "norm" in $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{d}]$, but I have not heard the generalized concept. Could you tell me where I can learn that?

Comment: @choco_addicted The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) has the definition. The norm of $x\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ is the determinant of $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $a\mapsto ax$ from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ to itself. From the definition, it is quite clear that the norm function is multiplicative. In $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$, the norm of $a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}$ is $a^3+3b^3+9c^3-9abc$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative solution. Working in $\mathbb F_3$, the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ factorises as $(x^2+1)^3$, and $x^2+1$ is irreducible. Thus 2 divides $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]$, and you showed 3 divides this as well.

Comment: I was going to give my overblown and overadvanced argument, and saw that yours encapsulated all my ideas in a short and comparatively elementary manner. Plus one.

Comment: I understand that $f(x)=(x^2+1)^3$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, but how can I know that the working in $\mathbb{F}_3$ implies that 2 divides $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$?

Comment: The minimal poly for $\alpha$ divides $f$ over $\mathbb Z$, so divides $f$ over $\mathbb F_3$.