# Prove $x^6-6x^4+12x^2-11$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Extracted from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise B1:

> Let $p(x) = x^6-6x^4+12x^2-11$, which we can transform into a polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$:
>   \begin{align*}
> x^6+1
> \end{align*}
>   Since none of the three elements $0,1,2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is a root of the polynomial, the polynomial has no factor of degree 1 in $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$. So the only possible factorings into non constant polynomials are
>   \begin{align*}
> x^6+1 &= (x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^3+dx^2+ex+f)
> \end{align*}
>   or
>   \begin{align*}
> x^6+1 &= (x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(x^2+ex+f)
> \end{align*}
>   From the first equation, since corresponding coefficients are equal, we have
>   \begin{align}
> x^0:\qquad & cf &= 1 \tag{1} \\
> x^1:\qquad & bf + ce &= 0 \tag{2} \\
> x^2:\qquad & af + be + cd &= 0 \tag{3} \\
> x^3:\qquad & c + f + bd + ae &= 0 \tag{4} \\
> x^5:\qquad & a + d &= 0 \tag{5} \\
> \end{align}
>   From (1), $c = f = \pm1$, and from (5), $a + d = 0$. Consequently, $af + cd = c(a + d) = 0$, and by (3), $eb = 0$. But from (2) (since $c = f$), $b + e = 0$, and therefore $b = e = 0$. It follows from (4) that $c + f = 0$, which is impossible since $c = f = \pm1$. We have just shown that $x^6 + 1$ cannot be factored into two polynomials each of degree 3.

For the second equation, however, $x^6+1=(x^2+1)^3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$.  So we cannot say $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ because $x^6+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I think (3) should read $af + be + cd = 0$

Comment: I think the following can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285615

Comment: What does the argument say after this? Surely it does not go on to somehow prove that the second case cannot happen?

Comment: A good find, @MichaelRozenberg!

Comment: Given the ambiguity [in another exercise from this chapter of Pinter](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3577096/11619) I'm gradually getting a less than high opinion of this tome. Not sure I want to locate a copy to check properly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, there's an online copy at http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf -- the OP's excerpt is from the solutions at the end of the book. It omits a final sentence, "Complete the solution." That same sentence appears in other (partial) solutions as well. Maybe it's missing from whatever version of Pinter the OP is using.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Barry. Admittedly I have very little exposure to textbooks with solutions to the exercises. Mostly for the simple reason that there too few Finnish speaking math students for publishers to be interested.

Comment: Not related to the question, but this polynomial can be shown to be irreducible also by noticing that all its roots lie outside of the unit circle, which together with absolute value of coefficient being prime implies irreducibility.

Comment: @Sil How do you notice that all its roots lie outside of the unit circle?

Comment: @Servaes You can notice it by using any tool that can plot the roots (e.g. Wolfram alpha, Maple...). Proving it is another matter, I guess we could utilize Rouche's theorem, I will think about simpler proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the second equation, however, $x^6+1=(x^2+1)^3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$.  So we cannot say $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ because $x^6+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_3$.  What am I missing here?

You are entirely correct here. What you are missing is that the preceding argument shows that $p$ is not a product of two cubics *in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$*. After all, if it were, then in such a factorization
$$p=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^3+dx^2+ex+f),$$
all coefficients are integers by Gauss' lemma, and hence this reduces to a factorization into cubics in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$. But you have just shown that no such factorization exists.

So it remains to show that $p$ is not the product of a quadratic and a quartic *in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$*, and there are *infinitely many* other primes to try. For example, in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$ you have
$$x^6-6x^4+12x^2-11=x^6+x^4+5x^2+3.$$
A quick check shows that this polynomial has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_7$. Now proceed as before, expanding
$$x^6+x^4+5x^2+3=(x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(x^2+ex+f),$$
to show that no such factorization exists in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$.

---

If you are comfortable with a little more abstract algebra, here is an approach that does not require such ad hoc calculations. First it is easy to see that in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ the polynomial $p$  factors as
$$p=x^6+1=(x^2+1)^3,$$
where $x^2+1\in\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ is irreducible. It follows that every irreducible factor of $p$ in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ has even degree. Now note that $p=h(x^2)$ where $h:=x^3-6x^2+12x-11\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$. A quick check shows that $h$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_7$, and therefore it is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$. This means the subring of the quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_7[x]/(p)$ generated by $x^2$ is a cubic field extension of $\Bbb{F}_7$, and therefore $p$ has an irreducible cubic or sextic factor. In the latter case $p$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$, and hence in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and we are done.

If $p$ has an irreducible cubic factor in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$, then this is the reduction of an irreducible factor of $p$ in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. As we saw before, the degree of this factor is even, so it is either quartic or sextic. Again, if it is sextic then $p$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and we are done. If it is quartic then its reduction in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$ is the product of a cubic and a linear factor. But $p$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_7$ because $p=h(x^2)$ and $h$ has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_7$, a contradiction.

Comment: For the upper part of your answer, however, $x^6 - 6x^4 +12x^2-11 = (x^3 + x^2 + x + 5) (x^3 + 6 x^2 + x + 2)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_7$.  Are you saying we can use different primes to check the irreducibility of the same polynomial into factors of different degrees?  That is, use $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ to check the irreducibility into cubic polynomials, and $\Bbb{Z}_7[x]$ to check the irreducibility into polynomials of degree 4 and 2?

Comment: @hchar Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. The fact that your polynomial factors into two cubics in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$ is of no consequence. Though if you can show that both cubic factors are irreducible, then it follows that all factors in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ are *at least* cubic.

Comment: In the second part of your answer, by $\Bbb{F}_3$ and $\Bbb{F}_7$, did you mean $\Bbb{Z}_3$ and $\Bbb{Z}_7$?  Or did you intentionally specify $\Bbb{F}_n$ to emphasize its relation to field extension?

Comment: @hchar It is simply the shortest way to refer to those objects. I could also have written $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}/(3)$. I reserve $\Bbb{Z}_3$ for the $3$-adic numbers; using it for integers mod $3$ can cause a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The answer is wrong but see my comment!

I think the reasoning should be like the following. As $p(x)$ has integer coefficients and is monic every zero of $p$ that lies in $\mathbb{Q}$ is also integer. But every integer zero of $p$ must divide the absolute term which is 11. Therefore, it could only be $\pm1$ or $\pm11$. Neither is a solution. The explanation above shows that $p$ cant be the product of two cubic polynomials. So if $p$ were reducible it had an irreducible quadratic monic polynomial with as factor which would have itself two zeros of the form $\pm\sqrt{q}+r$ whose square is in $\mathbb{Q}$. But then $p$ has only even powers of $x$ so substituting $x^2\rightarrow{}y$ gives a cubic polynomial which is either irreducible or has a linear factor. But then the same reasoning as above applies and since neither $\pm1$ nor $\pm11$ are zeros of that polynomial we are done.

Comment: My reasoning is wrong. But I don't want to delete the answer because it might be instructive anyway to see **that** it is wrong. I have a counterexample with degree 4. Let $p(x)=(x^2+x+3)(x^2-x+3)=x^4+5x^2+9$. It is clearly the product of two (irreducible but that's not important) polynomials. If I were right the polynomial $p_{1}(x)=x^2+5x+9$ that is derived from $p(x)$ by halving the exponents of $x$ should be the product of two linear polynomials. But $p_{1}(x)$ has a negative discriminant and is therefore irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score -3):

Let $p(x) = x^6 - 6x^4 + 12x^2  - 11$

Substitute $x^2 = y$

$h(y) = y^3 - 6y^2 + 12y - 11$

Letting $g(y) = h(y+2)$

$$g(y) = (y+2)^3 -6(y+2)^2 + 12(y+2) - 11$$

$$g(y) = y^3 - 3$$

$g(y)$ is obviously irreducible, thus so is $h(y)$ and $p(x)$.

Comment: $h(y)$ irreducible doesn't imply $p(x)$ irreducible.